# Publish iOS Application For Some people outside company

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, udid

Is there any way to distribute iOS Application for some users outside company apart from sending using Diawi or TestFlight

Comment: Use Fabric to distribute app outside company. This tool is very easy to use. https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/build-tools.html This will be also useful link. https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/distribute-beta-builds.html

Comment: You can refer below link for sharing ios app to other people:
http://mobiledan.net/2012/03/02/5-options-for-distributing-ios-apps-to-a-limited-audience-legally/

Comment: How many users do you want to distribute to ?